# How to add noise to gradient descent?

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient-descent

I have the following code where I have implemented gradient descent for a function using pyTorch. How do I add noise to the code so that it identifies both local minima?

```
import torch


startVal = -5.0
alpha = 0.001
space = " "
progressionCheck = True 

x = torch.tensor(startVal, requires_grad=True)

def function(a):
    f = a**4 - a**3 - a**2 + a - 1
    return f

for i in range(1000):
    function(x).backward()
    newVal = x - alpha * (x.grad)
    progressionCheck = function(newVal) < function(startVal)
    x = newVal.detach().clone().requires_grad_()
    print(x)

print("The minimum value occurs at" + space + str(float(x)))
print("The minimum value is" + space + str(function(float(x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you intend to disturb the gradients by some noise. To do so, you could specify a distribution e.g. as follows

```
low, high = -0.1, 0.1
dist = torch.distributions.uniform.Uniform(low, high)
```

and then sample from it to update the gradients, i.e. adjust

```
newVal = x - alpha * (x.grad)
```

to

```
newVal = x - alpha * (x.grad) * dist.sample([1]).item()
```

Altneratively, sample the noise in advance

```
noise = dist.sample([1000])
```

and then index it

```
newVal = x - alpha * (x.grad) * noise[i]
```

However, I doubt this fulfils the purpose and don't see how you could avoid multiple runs coupled with using varying start values (or, less beautiful, very large noise or step size)  to find multiple local minima.